# Passed speed variable to jQuery slideToggle() is ignored if in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

I'm having a strange issue, and my google-fu is failing me.  I'm working on a WordPress plugin, and I'm passing variables from the settings page to the jQuery script.  It's all passing perfectly fine, except that within the script, it's completely ignoring the value for the speed in slideToggle().

For the record, I'm loading a jQuery script (jQuery UI - v1.11.2): core and effects.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $show_open_by_default = wp_settings.expanded;
  var $showtext = wp_settings.show;
  var $hidetext = wp_settings.hide;
  var $speed = wp_settings.toggle_down;
  var $easing = wp_settings.easing;

  if($show_open_by_default != 1) { // if setting is unchecked...
      $('.comment .children').hide(); // hide all children on load
  }

  $('.comment-list > li').each(function() {
    if( $(this).find('.children').length > 0 ) {
      $(this).find('.children').before('<div class="replylink"><span class="show">'+$showtext+'</span></div>');
    }
  });

  $('.replylink').hover(function() {       // when hovering the replylink...
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');       // change the cursor...
  }, function() { 
    $(this).css('cursor','auto'); 
  }).click(function() {                     // and on click...
    // change the text
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == $hidetext ? $showtext : $hidetext); 

    // animate the visibility of the children
    var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
    var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

    if ($visibleSiblings.length == 0 ) {
        $visibleSiblings.slideToggle($speed, $easing);      
    } else { 
        $nextDiv.slideToggle($speed, $easing);
    }
  });
});
```

It all works perfectly fine, except for the slideToggle() call at the end.  If I place alert($speed); just before the slideToggle() call, it does, indeed, alert the correct setting just fine.  However, the slideToggle ignores it and reverts to the default speed.

What's funny is, if I *manually* put in a value, it works just fine.  But with the passed value, it ignores it.  I am completely stumped on this.  I've tried everything I can think of to make it pay attention to that number, but it will only do so if I hard-code it in the slideToggle() call.  If it's passed, it won't pay attention to it.  Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It will take the value of wp_settings.toggle_down;

Comment: Are you sure `$speed` (and `wp_settings.toggle_down`) is a number, not a string?

Comment: Yes.  The alert WILL show the numeric value, even if I place it directly before the call to slideToggle().

And Bhojendra - it *is* using that value.  I've tried using the variable and directly using wp_settings.toggle_down with the same result.

Comment: @Shelly, the alert will display the value regardless of its type -- both the `42` number and the `"42"` string will be displayed in the same way. However, only the former is suitable for `slideToggle()`.

Comment: I think I get what you mean - thank you Frédéric! I'm going to play a little and see if I can't fix this...

Comment: You are absolutely correct, Frédéric - that was the problem!  The passed value IS a string. I'm going to do some editing on the PHP end and try to get that fixed (because a string value is possible with "fast" or "slow").  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post the the solution was found - but the answer is in the comments. Basically, the passed value is a string, not numeric. So I have some conversion to do in my PHP file to be sure the value is passed correctly based on the type.